# An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile. Not able to run flutter project on iOS simulator getting pod error

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, cocoapods

I have setup a firebase project for my flutter project but while running the project I'm getting the below error. I have tried to install the pod properly but still, there is an error while executing. Please if you have any idea let me know. I have shared the console log

```html
- Generating dummy source at `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-dummy.m`
      - Generating deterministic UUIDs
      - Stabilizing target UUIDs
      - Running post install hooks
    [!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

    undefined method `each_child' for #<Dir:0x00007fd6d1da4a58>

    Documents/Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:57:in `block in flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    Documents/Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:54:in `each'
    Documents/Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:54:in `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    flutter-project/ios/Podfile:41:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
    flutter-projecty/ios/Podfile:40:in `each'
    flutter-project/ios/Podfile:40:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in
    `post_install!'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in
    `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in
    run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in
    `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in
    create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod
    s_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in
    create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in
    `create_and_save_projects'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, the issue with the podfile hence I have run the following command and it works.

> sudo gem install cocoapods

for more information I have raised this on GitHub you can find [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91343)

Answer (score 9):

navigate to ios directory then Run these commands

```
cd ios (navigate to ios directory)
flutter precache --ios
pod install
```

Comment: One tiny nuance here. If you are using flutter version manager, do not forget to run all flutter commands starting with fvm. Otherwise it will not solve the issue. That is: fvm flutter precache --ios

Comment: Elmars' comment was the missing nuance for me :)

Answer (score 1):

in your pod file,

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

uncomment this line and change 9.0 to 10.0 and run the app. it will take some time at the first. like 20 - 30 minutes.

Comment: I have already done that still getting the same error.