'The plist file at path doesn't exist' when running app on iOS
I am having issues running my flutter project on iOS. I have searched everywhere (and tried solutions from other SO threads) and cannot seem to find how to solve this error. I get the error:
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

If I scroll up a little, I see that the issue seems related to the plist file missing:
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.
[!] The plist file at path `/Users/user1/StudioProjects/flutterproject/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` doesn't exist.

Here is a longer version of the log from console: https://pastebin.com/s5JqKAcY
Here is my verbose flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-LV)
• Flutter version 3.19.5 on channel stable at /Users/user1/flutterdev/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 300451adae (7 weeks ago), 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
• Engine revision e76c956498
• Dart version 3.3.3
• DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15E204a
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • 3F02384A-7C4B-4D94-8BB0-97810C2C3461 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-4 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.158

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

The flutter project is using flutter version 3.16.5.
If I open the project in XCode and try to run it, it produces this error:
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/user1/StudioProjects/lflutterproject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

My current ruby version is 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23] and cocoapods- 1.15.2.
This error also pops up if I simply try to run pod update in the ios folder of the project so I assume it could be something to do with cocoapods but I am not an expert in this at all.
I can run the app on Android devices and emulators, I can also build and run iOS apps and new flutter projects on iOS.
Any help is appreciated, I am out of ideas currently.

Try to run https://stackoverflow.com/a/69521509/833395

I am really not sure how I managed to solve my issue since I have been trying to solve it for weeks but it seems that what finally did it was a combination of these commands (in no particular order):
flutter clean
sudo gem install cocoapods
flutter pub get

I will leave this question unsolved since I cannot pinpoint the exact solution, perhaps someone knows what exactly was the problem.
Last time I got this error, following this Github issue report, which @Shivbaba's son helped me find again, solved it.

Inside your .xcodeproj file, find the line which contains the path to the plist file. Make sure to adjust the path and the sourceTree to <group>
/* AppStagingInfo.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; name = AppStagingInfo.plist; path = MobileApp/AppStagingInfo.plist; sourceTree = "<group>"; };

